# Is there magnifier in Spyder?

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

When we place the mouse pointer in scroll bar in PyCharm 2021, a rectangular magnifier appears and that portion of code will be shown.
Is there such a tool in Spyder?

The below picture is a sample in PyCharm 2021.

[image]

Comment: I don't think Spyder has this feature but maybe could be interesting to check. If you want you can [create a new issue in the Spyder repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/new) to suggest this feature

Comment: Thank you [Daniel Althviz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15954282/daniel-althviz). I have created a new issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16097) .